# My script in Roblox works fine, but once I added a debounce, it still worked perfectly, but only sometimes?

Tags: lua, roblox, debouncing

For example: The script works fine in one game session, but then in another, it doesn't work at all; almost as if there's some sort of random chance for the script to be deleted or completely ignored. If I remove the debounce, there's a 100% chance for the script to work once again. What could possibly be going wrong here?

```
local radius = script.Parent
local light = radius.Parent.Light
local sound = radius.Parent.lighton

local debounce = false

radius.Touched:connect(function(hit)
    if debounce == false then debounce = true
        if game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent) then
            light.PointLight.Brightness = 10
            light.Material = "Neon"
            sound:Play()
            wait(5.5)
            light.PointLight.Brightness = 0
            light.Material = "Plastic"
            sound:Play()
            wait(0.5)
            debounce = false
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is one of scoping. The debounce will always be set to true, but will only sometimes be set back to false. If it doesn't get changed, the function will obviously never be run again. You'll want to avoid lines like `if debounce == false then debounce = true`, as they make it more difficult for you to notice that the debounce is not changed in the same scope.

Fixed code:

```
local radius = script.Parent
local light = radius.Parent.Light
local sound = radius.Parent.lighton

local debounce = false

radius.Touched:connect(function(hit)
    if debounce == false then
        debounce = true
        if game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent) then
            light.PointLight.Brightness = 10
            light.Material = "Neon"
            sound:Play()
            wait(5.5)
            light.PointLight.Brightness = 0
            light.Material = "Plastic"
            sound:Play()
            wait(0.5)
        end
        debounce = false
    end
end)
```

Note that both statements changing the value of debounce align.